# Specifics on Memcached's strategy for allocation after max memory has been reached

Tags: memcached

According to the Memcached [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewProgrammingFAQ#Why_Isn%27t_curr_items_Decreasing_When_Items_Expire?), the following occurs when an attempt to allocate a value to the cache is executed and the memory limit is reached:

> **When do expired cached items get
>   deleted from the cache?**
>
> memcached uses
>   a lazy expiration, which means it uses
>   no extra cpu expiring items. When an
>   item is requested (a get request) it
>   checks the expiration time to see if
>   the item is still valid before
>   returning it to the client.
>
> Similarly when adding a new item to
>   the cache, if the cache is full, it
>   will look at for expired items to
>   replace before replacing the least
>   used items in the cache.used items in the cache.

The question is, what exactly occurs when it replaces the 'least used items'. Does it simply maintain a rank by access for each key, or does it track access over a period?

For example. I add 2 items to the cache (A and B). The access patterns for A and B are slightly different. I access A 5000 times every hour while I access B once every second. According to the documentation, it seems that if I attempt to add another item (C) after two hours and the max memory allocation is reached, B will be removed. This is because B has only been accessed 7200 times while A has been accessed 10000 times.

Is this correct? If not, is there a sliding time window where access is tracked? For example, A would be removed if the window is 30 minutes because it would have been accessed 0 times in the last 30 minutes while B would have been accessed 1800 times.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an exact LRU.  In general, you shouldn't make any assumptions about availability of things in the cache.

An exact LRU would be a lot more expensive as things would be moving around too frequently.  Instead, memcached won't place an item at the head of an LRU if it's done so recently.

Comment: Thanks. When you say 'not an exact LRU' are you confirming that in the scenario described that B would most likely be removed? I was intrigued when I read the FAQ about the deletion algorithm. For example, if an item is accessed disproportionately more than any other item in a short space of time, it could theoretically live in the cache forever without ever being accessed again.

Comment: There's an LRU list per slab (this is the thing that makes finding space O(1) in practice).  A given item won't move to the beginning of the recency used list more than once over a given period of time (imagine a couple keys getting pounded a couple hundred thousand times a second).  Eventually, if space is needed at a particular size, items that haven't been used will work their way out.